# have wo reduce with one map in M/R program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, jobs

I have a question.. How can I have a mapreduce job with one mapper and two reducer that both reducer inputs come from map output? and each of reducers has its own output?
and one other thing is that can mapper have 2 or more inputs?

```
public static class dpred extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable>
 {
   public void reduce1(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        double beta = 17.62;
        DoubleWritable result1 = new DoubleWritable();
        double mul = 1;
        double res = 1;
         for (DoubleWritable val : values){
         //  System.out.println(val.get());
           mul *= val.get();
           }             
         res = beta*mul;
         result1.set(res);
         context.write(key, result1);
     }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void reduce2(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    double landa = 243.12;
    double sum = 0;
    double res = 0;
    DoubleWritable result2 = new DoubleWritable();
     for (DoubleWritable val : values){
     //  System.out.println(val.get());
       landa += val.get();
       }
    // System.out.println(sum);
     result2.set(landa);
     context.write(key, result2);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do the reducers perform the same function or different onces? Can you give us some more details?

Comment: no their functions are different. all the reducers give key and values from map output and one of them do + operation and the other do * operation. I edit my question and add the code. also I need another map function to read results of both reducers..

Comment: if the operation is this simple you could consider doing 2 context.write() in once reduce function (it's possible with `MultipleOutputs` to write them to different files if you want)

Comment: thanks.. so let me do your suggestion.. thanks alot

Comment: I will add is as an answer please vote to close question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the operation is this simple you could consider doing 2 context.write() in once reduce function (it's possible with `MultipleOutputs` to write them to different files if you want)